# Dropbox api upload to root directory?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I'm using dropbox-php-sdk and i cannot upload to root directory(team), i can only upload to account directory?  Instead of uploading to `home/Movies`, it is uploading to `home/Dave Smith/home/Movies`?

```
       //Configure Dropbox service
        $dropbox = new Dropbox($app);

        //Chunk Size
        $chunkSize = 8000000;

        $pathToLocalFile = '/home/mywebsite/public_html/assets/videos/input3.mp4';

        // Automatically create stream through file path
        $dropboxFile = new DropboxFile($pathToLocalFile);

        $file = $dropbox->uploadChunked($dropboxFile, "/home/Movies/input3.mp4", null, $chunkSize);
```

My dropbox account has full dropbox permissions to access all files/folders in teamspace.  The app/access token was created by team admin account.  How do i solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Dropbox API calls operate in the "member folder" ("/Dave Smith" in your example).

You can configure Dropbox API calls to operate in the "[team space](https://help.dropbox.com/teams-admins/team-member/team-space-overview)" instead though, by setting the `Dropbox-API-Path-Root` header. You can find information on using that in [the Team Files Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/dbx-team-files-guide).